# How to allow a user to select from provided list of handlers for my complex component?

Tags: storybook

The problem is simple: I have a component, which requires a handler for one of its parameters. A function handler. The component is written as follows (simplified):

```
const SelectInput = React.forwardRef<ComponentApi, ComponentProps>(function (
  {
    value,
    isDisabled = false,
    onMenuOpenOrClosed,
    ...otherProps
  }: ComponentProps,
  elRef
) {
  // componentCode
}) as React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  ComponentProps & React.RefAttributes<ComponentApi>
>;

export default SelectInput;
```

So, onMenuOpenOr closed is a function. The type is:

```
onMenuOpenOrClosed?: (isOpen: boolean) => void;
```

I just want to provide my testers a list of simplified typical handlers, like

```
function (isOpen: boolean){
  showNotification(`You ${isOpen? 'opened': 'closed'} the select menu`);
}
```

Now the only possibility to show the fact that some action happened, [is Storybook actions](https://storybook.js.org/docs/essentials/actions), which is not enough for me. I just want to provide my testers an opportunity to select from a list of typical function handlers. The other sufficient option for me is allowing to write actual function bodies inside [Storybook controls](https://storybook.js.org/docs/essentials/controls) (write their own handler), but I don't see such a possibility here.

Maybe there is a plugin that allows it?